# Django app with pandas processing not loading specific page on railway.app but runs fine locally, How to troubleshoot?

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am facing an issue where my Django application, that uses pandas processing code, is not loading a specific page when deployed on https://railway.app service and keeps giving an application server error, whereas it runs fine on a local server but takes more than 10-11 seconds for loading the specific page. I would like to know the possible causes of this issue and how can I troubleshoot it.

Note: I am using an API build with Django Rest framework.

View that renders the pandas processed data:

```
def nsebse(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        endpoint1 = rq.get('https://stockindex.up.railway.app/api/bse/').json()
        endpoint2 = rq.get('https://stockindex.up.railway.app/api/nse/').json()
        bseData = helperForBSENSE(endpoint1)
        nseData = helperForBSENSE(endpoint2)
        return render(request,'nsebse.html',{'bseData':bseData,'nseData':nseData})
    else:
        return render(request,'notauth.html')
```

Helper function used in above segment:

```
def helperForBSENSE(data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['id','date','open','high','low','close','adj_close','volume'])
    for i in range(len(data)):
        item = data[i]
        df.loc[i] = [item['id'],item['date'],item['open'],item['high'],item['low'],item['close'],item['adj_close'],item['volume']]
        df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    today, req_day = datetime(2023,1,12), datetime(2022,1,12)

    one_year_df = df[(df['date'] <= today) & (df['date'] > req_day)]
    fifty_two_week_high = max(one_year_df['high'])
    fifty_two_week_low = min(one_year_df['low'])

    day_high = df[df['date']==today]['high']
    day_low = df[df['date']==today]['low']

    previous_day = today - pd.Timedelta(days=1)
    today_close = float(df[df['date']==today]['close'])
    prev_close = float(df[df['date']==previous_day]['close'])

    today_open = float(df[df['date']==today]['open'])
    today_gain_or_loss = float(today_close - prev_close)

    data = {
            'today_open':today_open,
            'today_close':today_close,
            'prev_close': prev_close,
            'today_gain_or_loss' : today_gain_or_loss,
            'day_high':float(day_high),
            'day_low':float(day_low),
            'fifty_two_week_high':fifty_two_week_high,
            'fifty_two_week_low':fifty_two_week_low,
            'xAxis':list(df['date']),
            'yAxis':list(df['close']),
            }
    return data
```

here is a live deployment link: https://stockindex.up.railway.app (click on NSE/BSE or companies tab for the page with above said problem)

Answer (score 0):

So i figured out the answer...

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    item = data[i]
    df.loc[i] = [item['id'],item['date'],item['open'],item['high'],item['low'],item['close'],item['adj_close'],item['volume']]
    df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

i ended up profilng the above code segment and it took 20 seconds to do that(convert json reposnse to a dataframe) so i used a builtin method of pandas to that and significantly reduced the time taken from 20 sec to 3 sec

code used to replace above:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
```